# Responsive inline svg?

Tags: svg

This SVG icon is 640x640px. The toolbar is 48px high.
The icon should now automatically adjust to the height of the toolbar.
Accordingly, the blue area would have to be 48x48px.

However, the icon now occupies much more space than it needs.

I gave the svg a height of 48px. Better would be `height: 100%` but that does not work.

[my codepen](https://codepen.io/QJan84/pen/VQKorO)

Comment: Please dont post any code as picture.

Comment: Please add code, errors and data as text ([using code formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). In general, code/errors/data in text format »» code/errors/data as an image » nothing. Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Comment: I do not understand what you mean. I have not posted any code as a picture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing only the height to 48px leaves the width at 640px.  Because you have `width="640px"` specified on your `<SVG>`.

So the fix is simply to remove the `width` and `height` attributes from `<svg>`.

```css
body {
  margin: 5%;
}

.toolbar {
  position: realive;
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background: red;
  height: 48px;
}

.toolbar__section.flex-grow {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
  
.toolbar__section.bg-green {
  background: green;
}

svg {
  display: flex;
  height: 48px;
  background: blue; 
}
```

```html
<p><strong>Responsive inline svg?</strong></p>
<p>
 This SVG icon is 640x640px. The toolbar is 48px high.
The icon should now automatically adjust to the height of the toolbar.
Accordingly, the blue area would have to be 48x48px.

However, the icon now occupies much more space than it needs.

I gave the svg a height of 48px. Better would be "height: 100%" but that does not work.
</p>

  
<div class="toolbar">
  <div class="toolbar__section bg-green flex-grow">
    Logo 
  </div>
  <div class="toolbar__section">
    <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 640 640" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">
<title></title>
<g id="icomoon-ignore">
</g>
<path fill="#000" d="M603.794 613.188l-190.189-207.478c42.858-44.846 66.395-103.468 66.395-165.71 0-64.106-24.964-124.375-70.294-169.706s-105.6-70.294-169.706-70.294-124.375 24.964-169.706 70.294-70.294 105.6-70.294 169.706 24.964 124.376 70.294 169.706 105.6 70.294 169.706 70.294c55.226 0 107.595-18.542 150.027-52.655l190.178 207.467c3.156 3.442 7.471 5.188 11.799 5.188 3.862 0 7.736-1.391 10.808-4.205 6.513-5.972 6.954-16.093 0.982-22.607zM32 240c0-114.691 93.309-208 208-208s208 93.309 208 208-93.309 208-208 208-208-93.309-208-208z"></path>
</svg>

  </div>
  <div class="toolbar__section bg-green">
    Login Icon 
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Delete the `width` attribute from the svg element. You may have to adjust the `flex-grow` attributes in your toolbar afterwards.

See it [live on CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VQmYag).

Tested on Chrome 63.0.3239.132